# Setting Xdebug via WSL2 without an Ethernet cable

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2, xdebug-3

I have installed Docker on WSL2 machine (Ubuntu-18). PhpStorm installed on Windows machine.

I previously had Xdebug configured. And everything worked fine while the Internet was via an Ethernet cable. But now that I don't have an Ethernet cable, my Xdebug has stopped working.

```ini
xdebug.client_port = 9014
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.232.61
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = 1
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.log=/var/www/storage/logs/xdebug.log
```

Previously, I entered the IP address of the Ethernet (Windows machine). But now he's gone.

I tried use Default Switch IP address, but it doesn't work too.  I also tried use `host.docker.internal`, virtual IP address...

It's xdebug log:

```
[45] Log opened at 2022-08-08 11:27:14.740258
[45] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[45] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[45] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[45] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not discover client host through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.232.61:9014. :-|
[45] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 192.168.232.61:9014 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[45] Log closed at 2022-08-08 11:27:23.305499

[27] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[27] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[27] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[27] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not discover client host through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: 172.26.0.1:9014. :-|
[27] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 172.26.0.1:9014 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

[25] Log opened at 2022-08-08 10:13:21.411630
[25] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[25] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[25] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[25] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not discover client host through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9014. :-|
[25] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9014 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[25] Log closed at 2022-08-08 10:13:31.360631
```

Once again I repeat that all this worked when I used an Ethernet cable.

What do I need to write in `xdebug.client_host` line now?

Comment: It makes sense to try other interfaces' addresses if you have some in the `ipconfig` output

Comment: I tried to use all ip addresses

Comment: I also tried to use wsl2 ip address, but catch error Creating socket for '172.19.185.229:9014', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29